# WPF Resource File - Load Via Web Request and not by xaml file

Tags: .net, wpf

I have a legacy WPF application that has a series of resource files for different language translations:

- Translations.fr-FR
- Translations.ja-JP
- Translations.es-MX

etc...

At run time, when the user changes the language on screen, we change the current thread's culture and that magically picks up the correct translation file.

We now want to take the translation files off of the desktop and put them onto a server.  We have an endpoint that serves up the contents of the file based on the input culture code and it is no problem serializing the json into a Resource Dictionary back on the client.

The problem is that adding this dictionary into *System.Windows.Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries* does not seem to change the language.

Can Windows/WPF handle non file-based translation files?  The closest article I found is [here](https://www.codeproject.com/articles/515960/globalization-in-wpf-using-resourcedictionary), and he is also using local .resx files.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

So I was on the right track, but I did not mark the controls as Dynamic.  Once I did that, the correct resource was displayed.